# Bad KinematicMsg.msg in stdr_simulator

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone else have the problem in indigo that stdr_msgs/KinematicMsg.msg is incomplete? All its contents but `string type` seem to have been removed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226397/bad-kinematicmsg.msg-in-stdr_simulator/) by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 753 on 2016-02-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-02-12**:
from src or installed? which OS?
According to the [source code](https://github.com/stdr-simulator-ros-pkg/stdr_simulator/blob/hydro-devel/stdr_msgs/msg/KinematicMsg.msg) quite a lot of stuff is there.

Last release is 0.2.0 which according to

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-02-12**:
http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_indigo_default.html?q=stdr_msgs is actually release for indigo in Saucy and Trusty, but does not contain the noise parameters. They got introduced in commit `f13540d6cb45370de6b41d8`. Maybe you should try from source...

**Comment by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on 2016-02-25**:
Ubuntu 14.04. I installed via apt-get ros-indigo-stdr-simulator. When I do that, the KinematicMsg is empty except for one string value. I've tried multiple times. The error is easily reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `stdr_msgs/KinematicMsg.msg` released into indigo is, at the time of this writing, containing only [this data](https://github.com/stdr-simulator-ros-pkg/stdr_simulator/blob/6753c71b49d9e30fb3d32228a96e49f48e549011/stdr_msgs/msg/KinematicMsg.msg).
The noice values are only introduced in commit `f13540d6cb45370de6b41d8` ([see here](https://github.com/stdr-simulator-ros-pkg/stdr_simulator/commit/f13540d6cb45370de6b41d814abfb1719ed57ce3)) on May 21st 2015, which is not released yet. The last release originates from July 25th 2014.

So, you need to install an overlay of [this repository](https://github.com/stdr-simulator-ros-pkg/stdr_simulator) from source, to use those values...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-02-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0